# Reshape pandas dataframe to turn categorical columns into individual columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have data that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[list('ABCDE'), 
          ['Crude Oil', 'Natural Gas', 'Gasoline', 'Diesel', 'Bitumen'],
          ['Natural Gas', 'Salt water', 'Waste water', 'Motor oil', 'Sour Gas'],
          ['Oil', 'Gas', 'Refined', 'Refined', 'Oil'],
          ['Gas', 'Water', 'Water', 'Oil', 'Gas'],
          list(np.random.randint(10, 100, 5)),
          list(np.random.randint(10, 100, 5))]
          ).T
df.columns =['ID', 'Substance1', 'Substance2', 'Category1', 'Category2', 'Quantity1', 'Quantity2']

  ID   Substance1  Substance2 Category1 Category2 Quantity1 Quantity2
0  A    Crude Oil  Natural Gas      Oil       Gas        85        14
1  B  Natural Gas   Salt water      Gas     Water        95        78
2  C     Gasoline  Waste water  Refined     Water        33        25
3  D       Diesel    Motor oil  Refined       Oil        49        54
4  E      Bitumen     Sour Gas      Oil       Gas        92        86
```

The `Category` and `Quantity` columns refer to the corresponding the `Substance` columns.

I want to expand the `Category` columns as a new column for each unique value and have the `Quantity` value as the cell value. Non-existant categories would be NaN. So the resulting frame would look like this:

```
  ID   Oil  Gas Water Refined
0  A    85   14   NaN     NaN
1  B   NaN   95    78     NaN
2  C   NaN  NaN    25      33
3  D    54  NaN   NaN      49  
4  E    92   86   NaN     NaN
```

I tried `.melt()` followed by `.pivot_table()` but for some reason values get duplicated across the new category columns.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `pd.melt` then `groupby`:

```
np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[list('ABCDE'), 
          ['Crude Oil', 'Natural Gas', 'Gasoline', 'Diesel', 'Bitumen'],
          ['Natural Gas', 'Salt water', 'Waste water', 'Motor oil', 'Sour Gas'],
          ['Oil', 'Gas', 'Refined', 'Refined', 'Oil'],
          ['Gas', 'Water', 'Water', 'Oil', 'Gas'],
          list(np.random.randint(10, 100, 5)),
          list(np.random.randint(10, 100, 5))]
          ).T
df.columns =['ID', 'Substance1', 'Substance2', 'Category1', 'Category2', 'Quantity1', 'Quantity2']

pd.wide_to_long(df,['Substance','Category','Quantity'], 'ID','Num','','.+')\
  .groupby(['ID','Category'])['Quantity'].sum()\
  .unstack().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
Category ID   Gas   Oil  Refined  Water
0         A  19.0  54.0      NaN    NaN
1         B  57.0   NaN      NaN   93.0
2         C   NaN   NaN     74.0   31.0
3         D   NaN  46.0     77.0    NaN
4         E  97.0  77.0      NaN    NaN
```

Comment: This works, but not as is. It was creating a ton of duplicate columns and adding all of the numbers, resulting in inaccurate values. But adding two methods to the chain, `reset_index` and `drop_duplicates`, worked:

```pd.wide_to_long(df,['Substance','Category','Quantity'], 'ID','Num','','.+')\
  .reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset=['ID', 'Num'])\
  .groupby(['ID','Category'])['Quantity'].sum()\
  .unstack().reset_index()```

Comment: I'll add this nifty solution also needs some adaptation for the older `pandas` 0.19.